# SOC for router like a d-link?

Tags: system-on-chip

Anyone know of a SOC (System on Chip) that you could use for your own router? There probably many types of SOC, I'm looking for something that would run Linux (i.e. isolinux).

Looking for something with a low power consumption.

Some of the answer are suggestion using a existing router and replace the firmware. Sound great! I have a DLINK 825 and, for example, i like to add BOOTP to my router, so i can setup a bootable image (on a different server) but being served the dhcp of my router?

Comment: Unless you are talking huge volumes, your challenge may be as much finding a manufacturer willing to work with you as finding the theoretically best chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots from manufacturers like Broadcom, Atheros, Realtek, Ralink. Most modern routers are running a SoC with some external flash and RAM, and most are already running Linux. The dd-wrt, OpenWRT and Tomato third-party firmwares are all Linux-based.

You're better off getting an off-the-shelf router that has the firmware source code available, and simply study/customize it yourself.

EDIT: The D-link DIR-825 described is supported by OpenWRT (rev. B hardware only), which makes its source code available. It is theoretically possible to compile in other functionality so long as the end result image fits in the available flash. The specifics of BOOTP are better suited for another SE site.

Comment: Yes in general, but not sure the "most are already running Linux" comment really applies anymore - I'm under the impression that a lot of the low end off the shelf units have moved beyond running Linux to more compact proprietary stacks.  If you look at the compatibility pages for the alternative firmwares, there are a lot of device entries to the effect of No - insufficient ram or flash.

Comment: It's fairly easy to add flash or RAM - I've personally upgraded an old Netgear WGR614 with more flash and got dd-wrt going on it.

Comment: Thanks! I added some more to the question to be more specific.